# How evil would it be to use type punning between trivially copyable structs?

Tags: c++, type-punning

I have a library with a Swift interface that hides a C++ layer. In the C++, I have `struct A { ...}`. I want the Swift to pass around by-value copies of this struct (for various complicated reasons). Swift understands C declarations but not C++, so I'd need to declare some dummy C struct for it with the same size, e.g. `struct FakeA { char data[/* size of A */]; }`. Then, I could use type punning to go back and forth. Since `A` is trivially copyable, I would think it's OK. However, at cppreference.com it states, "Unlike in C, however, objects with trivial default constructors cannot be created by simply reinterpreting suitably aligned storage, such as memory allocated with std::malloc: placement-new is required to formally introduce a new object and avoid potential undefined behavior."

How *undefined* are we talking? Could it realistically cause problems, say, when compiling with Clang for arm64 and x86_64?

Comment: C++ supports type punning. It just doesn't support in-place type punning. I'm not seeing any indication that you need in-place type punning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ abstracts the concept of a [lifetime](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life), even for pods with no constructors, C++ defines in specific terms when lifetime starts and ends of an object, that's why you can't just reinterpret bytes from a memory even if you know their layout match. It is *undefined behavior* because that is not start of lifetime of the object.

In practice, this is the kind of of UB that people still use though, because there's no equivalent non UB option.

`std::start_lifetime_as<T>` and `new (p) std::byte[n]` (formerly `std::bless`) would be the perfect remedy for this (http://wg21.link/p0593) but sadly not for now.

Comment: use wg21.link/p0593 to get latest revisions, `bless` has been renamed.

Comment: Did any C++ committee ever express any particular intention to break C compatibility with constructs like `struct foo *p = (struct foo*)malloc(sizeof p); p->member = whatever;` or give any rationale for doing so, or did they expect that implementations would support such obviously-useful constructs without regard for whether they were actually required to do so?